# Triggers to update Master table with summary data from Details table(s)

Tags: mysql, triggers, mariadb

If we want to automate the summary fields in a mater_table with sum from the detail_table,
directly within the database (for example MariaDB), would it be better to use the sum of all records or to go with a record-by-record approach in the trigger?

For example:

**SUM() approach:**

```
-- Trigger to update summary data on INSERT
CREATE TRIGGER tr_insert_detail_table
AFTER INSERT ON detail_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE master_table
  SET total_amount = (
    SELECT SUM(amount)
    FROM detail_table
    WHERE master_id = NEW.master_id
  )
  WHERE id = NEW.master_id;
END;

-- Trigger to update summary data on UPDATE
CREATE TRIGGER tr_update_detail_table
AFTER UPDATE ON detail_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE master_table
  SET total_amount = (
    SELECT SUM(amount)
    FROM detail_table
    WHERE master_id = NEW.master_id
  )
  WHERE id = NEW.master_id;
END;

-- Trigger to update summary data on DELETE
CREATE TRIGGER tr_delete_detail_table
AFTER DELETE ON detail_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE master_table
  SET total_amount = (
    SELECT SUM(amount)
    FROM detail_table
    WHERE master_id = OLD.master_id
  )
  WHERE id = OLD.master_id;
END;
```

**OR record-by-record approach**

```
-- Trigger to update summary data on INSERT
CREATE TRIGGER tr_insert_detail_table
AFTER INSERT ON detail_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE master_table
  SET total_amount = total_amount + NEW.amount
  WHERE master_table.id = NEW.master_id;
END;

-- Trigger to update summary data on UPDATE
CREATE TRIGGER tr_update_detail_table
AFTER UPDATE ON detail_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE master_table
  SET total_amount = total_amount - OLD.amount + NEW.amount
  WHERE master_table.id = OLD.master_id;
END;

-- Trigger to update summary data on DELETE
CREATE TRIGGER tr_delete_detail_table
AFTER DELETE ON detail_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE master_table
  SET total_amount = total_amount - OLD.amount
  WHERE master_table.id = OLD.master_id;
END;
```

Comment: *would it be better to use the sum of all records or to go with a record-by-record approach in the trigger?* 2nd option is obviously more fast. But if total value become incorrect due to any reason then this incorrectness will stay (only separate recalculation will fix) for 2nd option whereas in the 1st option it will be fixed on the next data change. So decide what is more important for you - the speed or the preciseness.

Comment: One more. Your 2nd approach is incorrect in general, it will produce incorrect result if `amount` and/or `total_amount` is nullable and some value is NULL.